# An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done() method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm confused by the wording in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {});
>
> An alternative construct to the success callback option, the .done()
>   method replaces the deprecated jqXHR.success() method. Refer to
>   deferred.done() for implementation details.

I'm not confused about jqXHR.success - that apparently is deprecated.
But because jqXHR.done() is "an alternative construct", is the author saying to use .done or "the success callback option"?

Edit:

Maybe the author is saying that the .done method is an alternative because it gives you more features than the success callback.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Don't confuse `jqXHR.success` with the success callback ***option***. They are two different things.

Comment: "Yes" wasn't an answer I was hoping for.  Is the author saying to use .done or "the success callback option"?

Comment: I'm not confused about jqXHR.success - that apparently is deprecated.

Comment: sorry Phillip, i've quite misread your question

Comment: No problem.  The reason why it's a question is because I'm confused!

Comment: I guess the author does not say to prefer one to the other. As far (not far) as I understand the question, it would be adding to the "promises vs callbacks" matter...

Comment: I think I'm going to favor the .done method.

Answer (score 2):

jqXHR.done is an alternative to the success callback ***option***, for example,

```
$.ajax("foo.php",{
    success: successHandler
})
```

`$.ajax(...).success()` is of course deprecated.

It isn't saying you should use .done over the success callback option, it's just pointing out that it is a valid alternative. Use whatever makes sense in your code. You can use both if needed, the success callback option will be bound first, therefore it will get triggered first.

The main difference between using .done and success: is that .done() can be applied to a jqXHR after the request has been sent/received. For example,

```
var request = $.ajax(...);

request.done(function(){
    console.log("It's done!");
});

function doSomething () {
    request.done(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    })
}

$("#someel").click(doSomething);
```

Now, every time you click `#someel`, it will console.log the result of the ajax request without having to worry with whether or not it is done yet.

Or, maybe you want to get some content, but instead of going to the server on every click, just use the existing data.

```
$("#someel").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.data("request")) {
        $this.data("request",$.ajax(...));
    }
    $this.data("request").done(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

now it will only go to the server on the first click, after that it will using the existing data.

Comment: Is the author saying to use .done or "the success callback option"?

Comment: If both done and the success callback option are the same, then why are they both in jQuery?  Are there any advantages to one over the other?

Comment: the success callback was here first, and if removed will heavily impact a lot of code. Thats likely the primary reason it will never be removed. It also makes sense to have it since it is consistent with other jquery methods that have callbacks.

Comment: If the success callback was here first, then .done was added to improve something, right?

Comment: What improvement or advantage is done over the success callback?

Comment: Yes, it allows you to *easily* add multiple callbacks to the jqXHR in a way that allows you to separate different parts of your code. For example, one part of your code may send the ajax request, and then another can simply bind to it's done event without caring how or when it was sent.

Comment: Oh!  So I can have multiple dones but only 1 success callback!  Oh!

Comment: No, you can have multiple success, just pass it an array. But that's obviously harder to read than using multiple .done, and you can't add to it later.